# Change field label based on Record Type

Tags: record-type

In my organization we need to change the labels of Name based on Record Type.

Ex: If Record type is "Inventory" Name label should be displayed as a "Inventory Name" as well as if Record type is "Product" than name label must be "Product Name". So for this scenario is there any chances by standard functionality or we need to go for custom logic only?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? What's the use case here specifically?

Comment: That is the client requirement..nothing else.

Comment: There's no standard functionality for this

Comment: And do you know how to do that using custom logic?